# SAS Merge Issue

Tags: sas

So, I'm familiar with merges in SAS, and haven't had issues before, but I noticed an issue today that has never been an issue before.
For some reason the actual merging of observations is working properly in more complex data sets, however it only lists the variable values from one of the data sets (e.g. it doesn't overwrite missing values).

For instance, I wrote up this simple program:

```
data dataset1;
input id var1 var2 var3 var4;
cards;
1 . . 2 2
2 . . 2 2
3 . . 2 2
4 . . 2 2
5 . . 2 2
6 . . 2 2
7 . . 2 2
8 . . 2 2
9 . 2 . 2
10 1 . . .
;
data dataset2;
input id var1 var2 var3 var4;
cards;
1  2 2 . .
2  2 2 . .
3  2 2 . .
4  2 2 . .
5  2 2 . .
6  2 2 . .
7  2 2 . .
8  2 2 . .
10 . 1 . .
;


data dataset3;
merge dataset1 dataset2;
by id;
run;
```

This should yield the following:

```
id var1 var2 var3 var4
1   2    2    2    2
2   2    2    2    2
3   2    2    2    2
4   2    2    2    2
5   2    2    2    2
6   2    2    2    2
7   2    2    2    2
8   2    2    2    2
9   .    2    .    2
10  1    1    .    .
```

but instead, I get this:

```
id var1 var2 var3 var4
    1   2    2    .    .
    2   2    2    .    .
    3   2    2    .    .
    4   2    2    .    .
    5   2    2    .    .
    6   2    2    .    .
    7   2    2    .    .
    8   2    2    .    .
    9   .    2    .    2
    10  .    1    .    .
```

So, it's as if the merge is merging the observations and then just displaying the second data set's values.

I've tried to figure out the issue (I have a feeling it's something very basic I've just looked over), but I've no idea what's happening, since I've never come across the issue before.

Anyone know what's going wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are merging the datasets by `ID` but both datasets have the variables `VAR1-VAR4`.  So when both datasets contribute to an observations the one that is listed last in the MERGE statement will "win".

The reason you probably never saw this before is that normally when you are merging two datasets the only variables they have in common are the key variables. So the fact that the values read from the first datasets are overwritten by the values read from the second dataset didn't matter.

To get what you want you can use the UPDATE statement instead. Update will not replace a value with a missing value.  Basically it is designed to apply transactions to a master dataset.

Since it looks like each ID only has one observation in DATASET1 you could just use DATASEt1 as your master dataset.

```
data want ;
  update dataset1 dataset2 ;
  by id ;
run;
```